# Eclipse Indigo (Linux) not showing plugins after platform update

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04. After running "check for updates", one of the listed updates was Eclipse Platform ==> 3.7.2, which I couldn't select (white plug type icon). A conflict dependency was described, something to do with Java Development Tools, I think. Anyway, I force selected everything (which included the Eclipse Platform) and then manually deselected every other option except the Eclipse Platform. I was then able to go ahead with the update just for that option.

The update seemed to be going fine, but ultimately ended up with an error, which was that a file could not be deleted successfully (I believe it was `/usr/lib/eclipse/.eclipse` or something similar). After following some advice, I ran `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /usr/lib/eclipse /usr/share/eclipse` and then repeated the update process done previously, which worked.

After restarting Eclipse, all my plug-ins appear to be missing. Eclipse looks like it's completely stripped down. In the help menu, there's no longer any "Check for updates" option. Although in the installation details, the plug-ins are still listed.

I tried resetting ownership of the eclipse directories back to root, but it doesn't change anything. I've looked around at various bug reports and forums etc. but I'm not sure what to do. Can anyone help me?

**Error Log:**

```
Error
Sun Jan 19 11:50:37 GMT 2014
Error creating feature     

"file:/usr/lib/eclipse/features/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.user.ui_2.1.2.R37x_v20110815-1155-  
6-Bk8pYWZz0qUTX5I15GZWwbXkrl/".   
[/usr/lib/eclipse/features/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.user.ui_2.1.2.R37x_v20110815-1155-6-  
Bk8pYWZz0qUTX5I15GZWwbXkrl/feature.xml (No such file or directory)]
```

... followed by another similar entry, followed by:

```
Error
Sun Jan 19 11:37:42 GMT 2014
FrameworkEvent ERROR

org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle   
"org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins_1.1.100.dist [80]" could not be resolved. 
Reason: Missing Constraint: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse; 
bundle-version="1.0.0"
```

... followed by:

```
Error
Sun Jan 19 11:37:42 GMT 2014
Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.200.v20110815-   
1438.jar@1:start not found.
```

Comment: Can you paste the error you get in Window -> show view -> Error Log? That should give some clue of what went wrong

Comment: Updated, I'm not very familiar with Eclipse, so I didn't think to look there